# Is it possible to efficiently get a subset of rows from a large fixed-width CSV file?

Tags: c++, csv, io, fixed-width

I have an extremely large fixed-width CSV file (1.3 million rows and 80K columns). It's about 230 GB in size. I need to be able to fetch a subset of those rows. I have a vector of row indices that I need. However, I need to now figure out how to traverse such a massive file to get them.

The way I understand it, C++ will go through the file line by line, until it hits the newline (or a given delimiter), at which point, it'll clear the buffer, and then move onto the next line. I have also heard of a `seek()` function that can go to a given position in a stream. So is it possible to use this function somehow to get the pointer to the correct line number quickly?

I figured that since the program doesn't have to basically run billions of if statements to check for newlines, it might improve the speed if I simply tell the program where to go in the fixed-width file. But I have no idea how to do that.

Let's say that my file has a width of `n` characters and my line numbers are `{l_1, l_2, l_3, ... l_m}` (where `l_1 < l_2 < l_3, ... < l_m`). In that case, I can simply tell the file pointer to go to `(l_1 - 1) * n`, right? But then for the next line, do I calculate the next jump from the end of the `l_1` line or from the beginning of the next line? And should I include the newlines when calculating the jumps?

Will this even help improve speed, or am I just misunderstanding something here?

Thanks for taking the time to help

EDIT: The file will look like this:

```
id0000001,AB,AB,AA,--,BB
id0000002,AA,--,AB,--,BB
id0000003,AA,AA,--,--,BB
id0000004,AB,AB,AA,AB,BB
```

Comment: `seek` does you no good unless you're dealing with *fixed* record length down to the octet.  If you have fixed record lengths it's simple math. If you don't, then you have no choice but to enumerate newlines, one way or another, until you reach the line(s) you're interested in. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: ... but to continue on @WhozCraig's comment, if you process this file a lot, you could either create a binary file from it to make reading and positioning faster or create a second file containing line indexes (in binary form).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there some way to determine that? All the lines have the same number of characters, and each character, I assume takes up the same amount of space in memory. So I would think that all lines should have the same record length too, right?

Comment: If each line is *precisely* the same character count, newline included, then basic math will work. Otherwise an alternate indexing build like @TedLyngmo described is an option. You'll still pay the piper, but it will only happen once (assuming you're not doing something insane like trying to modify this 'thing' in place).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244204/discussion-on-question-by-many-questions-is-it-possible-to-efficiently-get-a-sub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I proposed in the comment, you can compress your data field to two bits:

```
-- 00
AA 01
AB 10
BB 11
```

That cuts your file size 12 times, so it'll be ~20GB. Considering that your processing is likely IO-bound, you may speed up processing by the same 12 times.

The resulting file will have a record length of 20,000 bytes, so it will be easy to calculate an offset to any given record. No new line symbols to consider :)

Here is how I build that binary file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::ifstream src("data.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream bin("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
    size_t length = 80'000 * 3 + 9 + 2; // the `2` is a length of CR/LF on my Windows; use `1` for other systems
    std::string str(length, '\0');
    while (src.read(&str[0], length))
    {
        size_t pos = str.find(',') + 1;
        for (int group = 0; group < 2500; ++group) {
            uint64_t compressed(0), field(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i, pos += 3) {
                if (str[pos] == '-')
                    field = 0;
                else if (str[pos] == 'B')
                    field = 3;
                else if (str[pos + 1] == 'B')
                    field = 2;
                else
                    field = 1;

                compressed <<= 2;
                compressed |= field;
            }
            bin.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&compressed), sizeof compressed);
        }
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;

    // clear `bad` bit set by trying to read past EOF
    src.clear();
    // rewind to the first record
    src.seekg(0);
    src.read(&str[0], length);
    // read next (second) record
    src.read(&str[0], length);
    // read forty second record from start (skip 41)
    src.seekg(41 * length, std::ios_base::beg);
    src.read(&str[0], length);
    // read next (forty third) record
    src.read(&str[0], length);
    // read fifties record (skip 6 from current position)
    src.seekg(6 * length, std::ios_base::cur);
    src.read(&str[0], length);

    return 0;
}
```

This can encode about 1,600 records in a second, so the whole file will take ~15 minutes. How long does it take you now to process it?

**UPDATE:**

Added example of how to read individual records from `src`.

I only managed to make `seekg()` work in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you @VladFeinstein. I will definitely try to implement the file encoding. But this will most likely be a future implementation. At the moment, I would like to understand how to use the seek() function to move around a fixed-length file. Will the src.read() function (which seems to copy into a buffer, the number of characters in the fixed-width) do the same thing as seek()? Or is seek() still better? If seek is still the preferred method here, could you I trouble you for an example of that? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @ManyQuestions please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The `seek` family of functions in `<iostream>` classes are generally byte-oriented. You can use them, iff you're absolutely confident that your records(lines in this case) have fixed count of bytes; in that case, instead of `getline`, you can open the file as binary and use `.read`  that can read the specified number of bytes into a byte array of enough capacity. But - because the file is storing text after all - in case even one single record has a different size,  you`ll get out of alignment; if the **id** field is guaranteed to equal the line number - or at-least an increasing mapping of it -an educated guess and a follow-up trial & error can help. You need to switch to some better database management fast; even a 10GB single binary file is too large and prone to fast corruption. You may consider chopping it into much smaller slices(order of 100MB maybe) so as to minimize the chance for damage propagation. Plus you gotta need some redundancy mechanism for recovery/correction.